# no results with ARIMA model in R

Tags: r, rstudio, data-mining, forecasting, arima

I am a beginner in R, and right now I'm working on a little project for studies.

I have a daily data set of air quality (no2, o3,...) and I'm trying to forecast the values.

what I'm doing is, I'm reading values for 2014, 2015 and 2016, and then try to predict values for 2017 (I have them so I can compare and evaluate the performance of the model).

Unfortunately, I don't get forecast results.

The question is: is it an error in my code or a lack of parameters?

For a while I thought that daily values are killing it, but I couldn't have proofs so I just went on.
the code worked for Air passengers forecast (monthly values), but not for air quality (daily values).

Thanks for helping!

[You can download my data Sets](http://www.mediafire.com/file/nqptpx4d565nxdj/DataStackOverflow.zip)

```
#Read data files
Data14 <- read.csv2(file = "indices_QA_commune_IDF_2014.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ",")
Data15 <- read.csv2(file = "indices_QA_commune_IDF_2015.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ",")
Data16 <- read.csv2(file = "indices_QA_commune_IDF_2016.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ",")

#Merge all data into one frame
completeData <- rbind(Data14, Data15, Data16)

#Filter data, we choose "75" for Paris
DataParis <- subset(completeData, ninsee == 75)

#isolate no2 values and store them in a vector
DataParisNo2 <- DataParis[['no2']]

#create a time series from the vector
tsno2 <- ts(DataParisNo2, start=c(2014, 1), end=c(2016, 12), frequency=365)

#verify if we have a time series (sucess)
class(tsno2)

#let's plot our series
plot(tsno2)

#we plot the mean value
abline(reg=lm(tsno2~time(tsno2)))

#Now we use log to make the variance equal in every point
#and we use diff to have a constant mean value
#our time series is now stationary and we can proceed
plot(diff(log(tsno2)))

#we apply ARIMA model

arima <- auto.arima(tsno2)
arima

ggtsdiag(arima)

#we generate forecast
forecast <- forecast(arima, level = c(95), h = 240)
autoplot(forecast)
```

[results for air quality forecast (current code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diVje.jpg)

[results for air passengers forecast (same method, almost same code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16XQb.jpg)

Comment: The code above *does* produce a forecast, it's the blue line in the plot. Whether that forecast can be improved is a different question. Most likely you have multiple seasonalities which are not well-handled by seasonal ARIMA models (also the fact that "daily" seasonality is not regular). The air passengers series is a classical series from the ARIMA literature so obviously has very good results with those models.

Comment: I see. Thank you Chris. So if I understood, the ARIMA model isn't the good one to use in my case. Any ideas/suggestions for me ? As à beginner it's tricky for me.

Comment: Finally, I will use TBATS model, I think it will be the best model to use in my project, better then ARIMA at least.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: TBATS will probably work well for this type of data, yes.